# Select conectando 3 tabelas no Firebird com IDs diferentes

Tags: select, firebird, join

Boa tarde,

Estou precisando fazer um select que retorne a **descrição** do produto,**código de barras** e **preço**.

A descrição e preço estão em uma tabela (TB_ESTOQUE) e o código de barras está em outra (TB_EST_PRODUTO).

Porém, os ID´s dos registros nas duas tabelas não batem pra fazer um JOIN direto, porque o cliente excluiu itens do estoque. Existe uma tabela de conexão (TB_EST_IDENTIFICADOR) entre is ID´s ID_ESTOQUE e ID_IDENTIFICADOR.

[image: Tabelas do banco]

O código que escrevi até então, foi o citado abaixo. Só que ele está retornando os itens igualando os IDs, juntando os registros das tabelas que tem o ID_ESTOQUE e ID_IDENTIFICADOR iguais em uma linha.

```
SELECT
    prod.id_identificador,
    est.id_estoque,
    prod.cod_barra,
    est.DESCRICAO as DESCRICAO,
    est.PRC_VENDA as PRC_VENDA
FROM
    ( TB_EST_PRODUTO prod
JOIN
    TB_ESTOQUE est ON prod.ID_IDENTIFICADOR = est.ID_ESTOQUE)
JOIN
    tb_est_identificador ident ON prod.id_identificador = ident.id_identificador
```

A tela do sistema é esta:
[image: Sistema]

Ai preciso que o select retorne estes itens como o sistema mostra.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui com o código abaixo. O que faltava era especificar o JOIN da tabela TB_EST_PRODUTO como LEFT.

```
select
    ident.id_identificador,
    est.id_estoque,
    est.descricao,
    est.prc_venda,
    prod.cod_barra
from tb_estoque est
    inner join tb_est_identificador ident
        on est.id_estoque = ident.id_estoque
    left join tb_est_produto prod
        on ident.id_identificador = prod.id_identificador
```